# Get the first value from a json array

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON coming from the database that's shaped like this:

```
var data = {
    "zone01": [{
        "region": "North",
        "state": "New York",
        "county": "Albany",
        "code": "01"
    }, {
        "region": "North",
        "state": "New York",
        "county": "Albany",
        "code": "05"
    }, {
        "region": "North",
        "state": "Maine",
        "county": "Auburn",
        "code": "07"
    }],
    "zone02": [{
        "region": "South",
        "state": "Florida",
        "county": "Gainseville",
        "code": "82"
    }, {
        "region": "South",
        "state": "Florida",
        "county": "Macclenny",
        "code": "73"
    }]
};
```

I'm trying to get a list of the first set of values "zone01", "zone02" etc... in order to populate a select input.  By selecting the zone you'll be able to select down the list but I can't seem to get a list of the zones.

I tried:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){
    var zone = JSON.stringify(element.index);
    $('#zone').append('<option value="'+zone+'">'+zone+'</option>');
});
```

but just get undefined.  Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybolanos/8mR4n/).

**UPDATED FINISHED CODE**

Here is my competed code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybolanos/8mR4n/9/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to use `index`, not `element.index`.

```
var zone = JSON.stringify(index);
```

`element` refers to the value on the right side of the colon. It does not have an `index` property.

`index` refers to the identifier on the left side of the colon. This is exactly what you want.

Comment: By the way, might be more clear to call it `key` or something, rather than `index`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.each(data, function(k,v){
    var zone = k;
    $('#zone').append('<option value="'+zone+'">'+zone+'</option>');
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mR4n/3/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're really looking for the first set of *indices*(or indexes). You can probably remove the `var zone` line, and just replace `zone` with `index` on the second loop line.

Also for future reference, if you have:

```
obj = { "akey": 5 };
index = "akey";
```

It seems like you tried to retrieve the value as "`obj.index`". The way to retrieve the number 5 would be like this...

```
obj[index] // evalutes to 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `zone` as follows

```
var zone = JSON.stringify(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with jQuery.each, but you can get the zone names like this:

```
for (var zone in data) {
  $(#zone").append('<option value="'+zone+'">'+zone+'</option>');
}
```